# fast convert xml to json xml (avoid CPU usage 100 and reduce RunTime)

Tags: python, json, xml, python-3.x

i know xml and json are not same and have diffrences but in my job i can convert them and xml contain `null` `true` `false`

so my code is :

```
#q = big XML (32000 line)
null = "null"
true = "true"
start_time = time.time()
q = eval(dumps(xmltodict.parse(q)))
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

i can't use `json.loads` because it convert `null` to `None` , `true` to `True`. after running my program i want to send it back to JavaScript and it cause error.

my problem is about **RunTime** for large xml (not too large just 2Mb) above code print 1.1480658054351807 secs and its very Bad.
is there any faster way to to this convertation

---

i don't know which information will help just can say my CPU is **intel xeon x5675**

Comment: First thing first: if you use `eval` then you're doing it wrong, period. Second thing: if you want to optimize, you have to know where the bottlenecks are, and the best way to do so is to profile your code (run it through a profiler and check the results).

Comment: aboat **eval**as i say becasue of `null` in xml have no more option ,  about profiler  its 1 line i know where is bottleneck

Comment: Of course you have other options, and it's not because "it's 1 line" that you know where the bottleneck is - this "1 line" calls quite a few other lines of code. But if you know better then why post a question here ?

Comment: you are right. i try `json.loads` its better than `eval` (a little faster , 2/3 run time) but u mean i find bottleneck in module and change it ?

Comment: Either this (xmltodict is FOSS, you have the right to fork and modify it) or at least understand why it takes so much time so you can assess which other solution would be faster (if there's one).